# Is there a way to rerequest permissions to a newly created page without deleting the `manage_pages` permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I am working on a web application that requests access to the pages managed by a user. It was working perfectly until I found an use case which apparently needs requesting `manage_pages` permission again.

Imagine the user gives permission to an application to access all of their pages (e.g. "Page 1" and "Page 2"). Now let's suppose they created another page ("Page 3"). What happens is: the application only have access to the first two pages and `/me/accounts` only returns "Page 1" and "Page 2". When I use the parameter `auth_type=rerequest` in another request, it does not prompt the permission dialogue since the `manage_pages` was already given (I reckon).

Is there a way to ask the user to give permission to their pages again without having to revoke permissions? The problem with revoking is that the application would have to delete users previously authorized `manage_page` on every login, since we would not know when a new page was created.

edit: including image of the page selector dialogue

[image: page selector]

Comment: This should not happen to begin with. If you have the permission, then you should be able to get all the pages the user manages, no matter when they were created. Have you actually verified that things change after you removed the permission and granted it again? If it did, then you should file a bug with Facebook.

Comment: It looks like the user can select the pages to give permission. On the aforementioned example, if I revoke users permission, the permission dialogue would show up again and now with the three pages. I included an image with the page checkbox on the original question.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. At the time I connected my Facebook App to my account, I had several pages, but only granted permissions for some of them; later when I tried to (re)assign permissions to the new added page or to the ones I skipped before, I just can't get permission dialog box. If i ask for a token of the new page or the skipped ones, there's no error from Graph API or SDK, but only an empty response. Using getReRequestUrl() method, instead of getLoginUrl() as mentioned on Facebook documentation gives no results as well. I was wondering if you found any solution for this issue?